# How to activate a site in lighttpd

Tags: apache, virtualhost, lighttpd

I am a newbie to lighttpd maintenance. In apache2 when I add a site(virtual host) file to sites-available, I will have to use the a2ensite command to activate it. If the vhost is example.conf, I will have to run the command below to activate it.

```
sudo a2ensite example
```

and then restart apache.

I see there are other sites which are in the conf-enabled folder, but I cannot see mine. I even ran lighttpd-enable-mod on the conf file, but for some reason I cannot find a symlink even though I restart the lighttpd server.

How do I do the same in lighttpd??

EDIT: I am adding the vhosts

> vhost1 >> conf-available/subdomain1.conf

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "subdomain1.example.com" {
#$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8081 ) ) )
}
```

> vhost2 >> conf-available/subdomain2.conf

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "subdomain2.example.com" {
    #$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
    ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8082 ) ) )
    }
```

So now I am adding another sub domain(subdomain3) on port 8083. And when I restart it I am unable to get to subdomain3. My web admin helped me on this and now he is out on vacation for two weeks, I primarily am a web developer, so I do not have a lot of idea around this.

One thing I noticed is, there are sym links for subdomain1.conf & subdomian2.conf, but I do not have a sym link to my subdomain3.conf file. When I do a `curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8083/`, I get a 200 and am receiving the expected data.There are no errors in the conf file, becaus it is a mirror image of the other files, except for the port and host.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing like that is needed just add a `if` case for the specific url/baseurl your side is supposed to be reachable from, save the config.

Make sure the config has no syntax errors via `lighttpd -t /path/to/config` and restart lighttpd afterwards (nowadays `systemctl restart lighttpd.service`, old `/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart`)

Keep in mind that `lighttpd` does not evaluate nor care about `.htaccess` or alike apache config files.